# Space between top and listview

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Hey everyone  can help to solve space between  `ListView` widget and top widget top widget is the svg image also i make scaffold background color red to see space and `ListView` background

This is image of the app
[image]

This is example i went

This link is source code
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15UIyRZXj8bDRQeTBdyxGFvQ90SxCJJjq?usp=drive_link

Comment: share code with question.

Comment: Please add the code directly to the question instead of a link or an image

Comment: please https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what if when we screen then that space is fill or show as it is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String svgString = '''
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="1080" height="500" viewBox="0 0 1080 500" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
</defs>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 540 540)" id="8c766263-7764-4e86-b9a4-b2e3930bc2c2"  >
<rect style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; visibility: hidden;" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"  x="-540" y="-540" rx="0" ry="0" width="1080" height="1080" />
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 540 540)" id="78c73894-81ea-4bfa-93f9-772aa0957680"  >
</g>
<g transform="matrix(-14.81 0 0 -14.81 540 -20.88)" id="16b0c9d9-48d4-4230-9fb3-b57678935c9d"  >
<path style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(101,101,101); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"  transform=" translate(-50, -50)" d="M 18.315 23.231 L 81.684 23.231 C 84.294 23.231 86.48 25.084000000000003 86.48 27.400000000000002 L 86.48 60.235 C 86.48 62.504 84.29400000000001 64.403 81.684 64.403 L 54.877 64.403 L 38.035 76.77 L 44.42999999999999 64.405 L 18.315 64.405 C 15.650000000000002 64.405 13.519000000000002 62.506 13.519000000000002 60.237 L 13.519000000000002 27.401 C 13.519 25.084 15.651 23.231 18.315 23.231 z" stroke-linecap="round" />
</g>
</svg>
''';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: [
          Padding(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35),
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                ...List.generate(
                  20,
                  (index) => ListTile(
                    title: Text('Item $index'),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SvgPicture.string(
            svgString,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following ways to achieve the results:

**1. Remove padding in list view**

Usually, listview has padding in it. You can remove as following:

```
padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

**2. Space around svg**

You need to crop the svg in editors. There are spaces around the images or svg, you need to crop to remove this. To remove space around the SVG, follow [this](https://svgcrop.com/) link.

**3. Use Stack widget**

If none of the above solutions work, you can use the Stack widget. In stack you can use Positioned to adjust the listview, you can give any position you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the default top padding of the ListView by wrapping it with a **MediaQuery.removePadding** widget and setting **removeTop** to true.

```
return MediaQuery.removePadding(
    context: context,
    removeTop: true,
    child: ListView.builder(
     .......
    )
  );
```